# Confusion in form.save() in two different models

Tags: html, django, get, save, modelform

I am having problems in displaying the page due to models. I honestly don't know what the problem is and every solution I see here is beyond me, since I am only beginning to learn Django. Here's the summary:
I have created two forms from two models(which are interrelated) and rendering the data from those forms in a single page. The data displays fine on the dashboard panel and the submission does save it to the database. I have tried overriding the save function in form but with no result. However, whenever I try and load the pages containing same data (display pages like home for customers)I am hit with:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shahi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\shahi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\shahi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Softwarica\3rd semester\Modern Web\Assignment\Project - Farmer's Market\farmersmarket\home\views.py", line 9, in index
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
  File "C:\Users\shahi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shahi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 559, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "C:\Users\shahi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 419, in get
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
shop.models.Order.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Order -- it returned 2!
```

The code in forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from shop.models import *

class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('customer',)

class OrderItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('item', 'status',)
```

views.py

```
def createOrder(request):
form_order = OrderForm()
form_orderitem = OrderItemForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    # print('Printing POST', request.POST)
    form_order = OrderForm(request.POST)
    form_orderitem = OrderItemForm(request.POST)

    if form_order.is_valid() and form_orderitem.is_valid():
        form_order.save()
        form_orderitem.save()

        return redirect('/dashboard')

context = {'form_order': form_order, 'form_orderitem': form_orderitem}

return render(request, 'dashboard/order_form.html', context)
```

I have tried overriding the save function in form but with no result.

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I just updated the question with entire error traceback.

Comment: The line in somewhere in your code raises the exception, `order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)`.

Comment: that is not the view causing the error. Check line 9 in views.py

Answer (score 0):

get() cannot be used for when more than 1 objects are returned. try with filter().

Do check first() or last(), if it helps you.

Comment: Yes, I did try that and it works if there is enough data(more or equal to 2). However, if there's only one data, the error says that not enough data is pulled. I was also hoping to find an efficient way to save form data into more than one models. Thanks!